# Can't set methods in add_url_rule

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to wrap my Flask server in a class, so as to better fit in the structure of the rest of my application.

I have the below code:

```py
class HTTPServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', self.hello_world, methods=['POST'])
        self.app.run(port=5050, use_reloader=False)

    def hello_world(self, data):
        print "Hello, World: {}".format(data)
```

However, if I send a `POST` request to `localhost:5050/index` I get a 404 error.

The Flask log shows the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2019 11:17:52] "POST /index HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The same happens if I change `['POST']` to `['GET']` in `methods` and send a `GET` request.

However, if I remove the `methods` parameter from `add_url_rule()` entirely, I can send `GET` requests and they are handled appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand the `endpoint` parameter of `add_url_rule`. It isn't the endpoint as seen by the client, but rather an internal name for the endpoint. The correct method call is:

```py
self.app.add_url_rule('/index', 'hello_world', self.hello_world, methods=['POST'])
```